# Getting error about "no member 'setTitle'" on my button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm getting the wrong message from Xcode about my piece of code (which is perfectly fine). I posted a screenshot of my work. Please help me with this so I can do the rest.

[image]

Comment: The error says that `lightButton` needs to be declared by `UIButton`

Answer (score 1):

With `lightButton` you are calling an `IBAction` you defined before (which is actually highlighted by Xcode, by the way). Since your `IBAction` doesn't return anything, you can't access any properties.

**Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'setTitle'.**

The `(_) -> ()` syntax represents a function, where the first parentheses represent the function's arguments, the second one the return type.

You should define an `IBOutlet` which connects to the Storyboard.

```swift
class YourController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton?

  // Usage:
  func someFunction() {
    myButton.setTitle('Title')
  }

}
```